# How can I retrieve an object using an ID in a static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a base class called `Object` with an `Id` property and a static method called `Find()` in it.

```
public class Object
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public static Object Find(string id)
    {

    }
}
```

I also have a a few other classes `Customer` and `Company` that inherit from this class. And at certain points, I need to find the specific `Customer` or `Company` by using the inherited `Find()` method and passing in the `Id`. Like this:

```
var savedCustomer = Customer.Find(customer.Id);
var savedCompany = Company.Find(company.Id);
```

I obviously cannot use `this` to return the object as it is a static method, so I'm having trouble finding a way to locate the object (whether it's a `Customer` or `Company`) with the matching `Id` so that I can return it.

I've searched all over the place and cannot seem to find a solution that works. I'm still learning `C#` and `ASP.NET` so I may just be unaware of a simple solution to this problem..

Is there any simple way to use the `Id` of an existing object in order to find it in a static method like this? Or is it just not possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you sure making a class called "object" is a good idea?

Comment: Where does the object exist and where are you "searching" for it? Is this in a DB? Are you using entity framework?

Comment: The base class can be named anything. I just called it that in the explanation. And right now they only exist within the class. A little before the `Find()` method is called is where I instantiate the objects. There's no DB

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should persist objects in a real persistence store, like a database.

If you really want to do this, your object can have a `static` property something like this:

```
private static List<Object> _list;

public static List<Object> {
   get {
       if(_list == null) _list = new List<Object>();
       return _list;
   }
}
```

You can then find by ID in this list. Note, I don't think you should actually do this. I suspect you come from a language with global variables and are trying to replicate this. C# doesn't have global variables. You will run into trouble trying to use `static` like this. For instance, if you run your ASP.NET application over multiple servers, your `static` variables will have different values per server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need some data structure to store your Customer instances in so you can find them. Lets keep it simple and go with a `Dictionary`.

Before we start I'm going to suggest you skip the static `Find()` method. This is getting very close to the [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern. It's popular in lots of frameworks (primarily RoR) but I'm just going to state my distaste for it. Mainly on the grounds of mixing data types and persistence. I've said my part, lets go.

So we'll add a static dictionary to keep track of our objects.

```
    public class Object
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }

        private readonly static Dictionary<string, Object> objectCollection = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

        public Object(string Id)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            objectCollection.Add(Id, this);
        }
        public static Object Find(string id)
        {
            return objectCollection[id];
        }
    }
```

Oops, see how we now need to have the Id in the constructor in order to add this in the collection? It means either the setter of the Id property has to be private or you need to update the collection on set (not shown). This object is getting more complex and really it just holds a string. You really should create another component to manage the collection! But that's a separate question.

Plus you're extended classes are going to either implement their own or have to do some casting.

Lets write that collection using generics shall we?

```
    public class Object
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjectCollection<T> where T : Object
    { 
        private readonly static Dictionary<string, T> objectCollection = new Dictionary<string, T>();

        public void Add(T newObject)
        {
            objectCollection.Add(newObject.Id, newObject);
        }
        public static Object Find(string id)
        {
            return objectCollection[id];
        }
    }
```

I don't know about you but I like that more, it keeps your object (and any extensions of it) very simple and lets you tinker with how you store it (dictionary,  serializing to files, storing in a DB) separately.

Comment: Thanks! This actually was very helpful and pointed me in the right direction.